# Was the impossibility of the second degree perpetuum mobile in the General Relativity ever proven?

Tags: general-relativity, thermodynamics, perpetual-motion

Somewhere I've heard, that gravity often likes to work against the entropy. For example, the surprisingly low temperature of the black holes. Or see the gravitational separation of different elements in a star (lowering its entropy).

As I know, thermodynamics is mainly a combinatorical thing on its lowest level. It is clear, pure math which shows, the entropy of a closed system doesn't decrease (ok, maybe with the exception of very small fluctuations).

But on my naive intuition it is not really trivial, how changes this math if it is about a closed physical system governed by the GR. It will be probably much more complex, probably highly over the graduate level. Was it ever proven, that a such system doesn't exist (which is govered by both of the thermodynamics and the GR and it could lower its entropy)?

Comment: Pure maths doesn't show that entropy doesn't decrease: it is an experimental fact and hence we assume entropy to be described by a convex function whose maximum is at equilibrium. About the rest I didn't really understand the question.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Is it really only an [experimental fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_%28statistical_mechanics%29)?

Comment: Yes, because you don't _prove_ that the entropy is maximal at equilibrium, you define it so that it is so and show that thermodynamics follows (which is the experimental assumption that allows you to define the entropy in the first place). As for the microstates it is still experimentally true that a system evolves maximising their number, hence the entropy must be somehow proportional to any monotonously increasing function thereof.

Comment: Can you give an example of how gravity (Newtonian gravity is fine, no need for GR) is supposed to "work against entropy"?

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, I gave two examples in my question.

Comment: Neither of those examples lowers the entropy, they merely challenge the student to learn how to draw proper system boundaries. In both cases you have simply neglected the entropy of the radiation and thus arrived at the wrong conclusion by making a trivial beginner's mistake. So I ask you again to submit a, this time correct, case in which gravity lowers the entropy of the entire system.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Ok. Then I try to reformulate into a more clear form. 1. We have the laws of the GR, it has an exact mathematical description. 2. We have the laws of the thermodynamics, it also has an exact mathematical description. 3. Was it ever proven, that these don't contradict? (4. If they do, at least theoreticaly would be possible to construct a perpetuum mobile of the second art in a GR system.)

Comment: @GennaroTedesco If you think this more formal question is better, I would be happy to switch the main question into this.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ok, thank you. I intentionally avoided to state that the gravity would lower the whole entropy in these examples. My question is that was it ever proven, that a such system doesn't exist.

Comment: Which brings us back to Gennaro's comment. "Proof" in physics is always experimental. You would have to find yourself a real gravitating system that violates thermodynamics and that would be "proof". To the best of my knowledge no such system has been identified. If, OTOH, you could do a calculation on a gravitating system that does that (using the correct system boundaries), then I would suggest that it would be better to modify the theory of gravity than to give up on thermodynamics which I regard as more fundamental, by far.

Comment: @CuriousOne Finding a such system is highly over my skills, but I think, if a contradiction would be found between their math, it would make probably possible to construct one (in theory). This is why I am curious, if a theoretical result around this topic already exists.

Comment: I haven't heard of any. I can't vouch for Newtonian gravity, but general relativity seems to be a thermodynamic theory in the sheep's skin of a geometric theory, so it's more likely that it (or a properly used version of it) actually approximates thermodynamics rather than to break it.